# Subtract comma value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi i have two values with comma and i want to get the difference between the two values. (For Example: 10,35 - 9,33)

```
<xsl:template name="getUPEDifferenz">
<xsl:param name="preisHersteller" />
<xsl:param name="preisDokument" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="($preisDokument != '' and $preisDokument != 0) and ($preisHersteller != '' and $preisHersteller != 0)">      
        <xsl:value-of select="$preisDokument - $preisHersteller" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>  
        <xsl:text>nicht angegeben</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

```
<fo:table-cell padding="5px" border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" text-align="right">
    <fo:block font-size="10px" font-weight="normal">
        <xsl:if test="boolean(Listenpreis)">
            <xsl:call-template name="getUPEDifferenz">
                <xsl:with-param name="preisDokument" select="format-number(string(Gesamtpreis), '###.##0,00', 'european')" />
                <xsl:with-param name="preisHersteller" select="format-number(string(Basispreis), '###.##0,00', 'european')" /> 
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <Haus>
    <Teile>
        <Position Nummer="1">
            <Benennung>Das Haus 1</Benennung>
            <Gesamtpreis>27.65</Gesamtpreis>
            <Basispreis>24.04</Basispreis>
        </Position>
        <Position Nummer="2">
            <Benennung>Das Haus 2</Benennung>
            <Gesamtpreis>27.65</Gesamtpreis>
            <Basispreis>24.04</Basispreis>
        </Position>
        <Position Nummer="3">
            <Benennung>Das Haus 3</Benennung>
            <Gesamtpreis>133.29</Gesamtpreis>
            <Basispreis>115.9</Basispreis>
        </Position>
    </Teile>
  </Haus>
</Root>
```

Thats the given code. The xml file itself and the xsl file.
But i get 'NaN' as a result. Can anybody help? I want to get the difference between the `Gesamtpreis` and `Basispreis` for each `Position`.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your XML. In particular, how are the elements `Gesamtpreis` and `Basispreis` shown in your XML? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this part:

```
<xsl:call-template name="getUPEDifferenz">
    <xsl:with-param name="preisDokument" select="format-number(string(Gesamtpreis), '###.##0,00', 'european')" />
    <xsl:with-param name="preisHersteller" select="format-number(string(Basispreis), '###.##0,00', 'european')" /> 
</xsl:call-template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:call-template name="getUPEDifferenz">
    <xsl:with-param name="preisDokument" select="Gesamtpreis" />
    <xsl:with-param name="preisHersteller" select="Basispreis" /> 
</xsl:call-template>
```

and then change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$preisDokument - $preisHersteller" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($preisDokument - $preisHersteller, '#.##0,00', 'european')" />
```

The idea here is to perform the subtraction with the original values, while the decimal separator is still a period - which is the only decimal separator XML allows.

Untested because a complete example has not been provided.